# After update to VS 16.9.0: Feature 'init-only setters' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csvhelper

We have a project that targets `netstandard2.0` and that project uses the NuGet package [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper), that is also available as `netstandard2.0`.

This project contains the class `CsvConfiguration` that is build as:

```
public class CsvConfiguration
{
    public virtual string Delimiter { get; init; }
}
```

And we use this library without any problems in the past. After updating Visual Studio from 16.8.6 to 16.9.0 the above mentioned error message occurs on a build:

```
error CS8370: Feature 'init-only setters' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.
```

While I understand why this error would occur, if I would use this feature in my own code, I don't know why this happens if a third party library uses it, that is declared to match my framework version.

Is this a *bug* in the library or in Visual Studio? Cause in VS 16.8.6 it compiles fine and in VS 16.9.0 it fails.

I know, an *easy* workaround would be to add a `<LangVersion>` entry within our .csproj file, but is this the recommended way?

Comment: Specify `<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>` in csproj.

Comment: @FrankQ.: That's suggestion 3 from Marc. ;-) But I upgraded to the latest version of the package that doesn't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks to be a badly-advised breaking change in the library, that was [added at the end of January](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/commit/4087082f46d2d977a5676382b94493a3ba35d695) and which has [already been reverted](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/commit/4d0f9ddb62dd0bf11ba1b1ce249d0cfb34db1e96). Changing from `set` to `init` is a fundamentally breaking change that introduces a `modreq` which is only understood in recent C# versions.

It is *odd* that it would compile in VS 16.8.6, and honestly: I find that unlikely - it *should* fail, but with an error message about an unknown `modreq` (as opposed to failing but knowing why). I suspect that what is more *likely* is that you have also updated the library version to the post-January version that introduced the problem, and you're now seeing the failure.

Fixes:

1. revert to a version before the end of January that doesn't yet have the breaking change
2. update to a newer version after the revert, that doesn't have the breaking change *any more*
3. use `<LangVersion>` in the csproj to choose a more recent C# version; since the compiler you're using *knows what the specific problem is*, you definitely have a compliant compiler - it is simply being *restricted* to down-level C# features

Ultimately, the entire point of `modreq` (as opposed to `modopt`) is that the compiler *must* understand a `modreq` to use a type/member, but the compiler can silently ignore a `modopt` if it doesn't understand what it means. I find it unlikely that an old version of the C# compiler was happily ignoring a `modreq` that it didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and we're going to update the NuGet package. But it seems that this bug (allow init in netstandard2.0) was fixed in VS 16.9.0, cause we checked out our solution (same commit) on different developer machines. Only difference was the installed version of VS (cause some already updated, some not) and the error doesn't occur on 16.8.6. Due to the fact that this is also just a library in our solution and the starting application is .Net 5 everything also worked at runtime in the past.

Comment: Just update CsvHelper NuGet Package to the latest version (now it's 26.0.1) and the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why it worked before, but according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version page, **.Net Standard 2.0** is bundled with **C#7.3** (which also is applied by the error message). **C#9** is only awailable for **.Net 5**.

You might try to report this as a bug to Microsoft (since it worked before) but i don't think you will get very far.

Comment: "C#9 is only available for .Net 5." - that is simply not true; you can use C# 9 to target any framework; some features require the presence of types that are added in later versions, but in most cases you can either a: not use those features, or b: add the types separately